# VS platform toolset on the command-line, for use with make-files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a portable CLI tool that builds on the command-line using a simple make-file. I have adapted the make-file so it builds using NMake and the VC++ command-line tools, but I can't figure out how to request the "vs120_xp" toolset.

I'm aware I can set the "vs120_xp" toolset for a new VS project and build inside the IDE or using MSBuild on the command-line, and it works fine, but I want to avoid converting my whole make-file if possible.

Is there any argument I can pass to the "vcvarsall.bat" or "vcvars32.bat" scripts, some arguments to NMake, some pre-processor definitions in the make-file, or some global settings somewhere, that I can use to control this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK for XP support after vcvarsall.bat you need somethin like this:

```
set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
set CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_;%CL%
set LINK=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01 %LINK%
```

You can also check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx) article

Comment: I do it for build boost on my project, but I'm not sure